# Using subprocess on an already running script to monitor return code

Tags: python

Im trying to create a way to catch errors on my database import script as it takes a very long time to run.

I was trying before to monitor the communicate() before of my docker exec command, but until recently I learned that the script in question "import.pl" is run outside of docker, and I can monitor it with

```
ps aux | grep perl
```

So this is what I currently have,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import subprocess

cities = ["x","y", "z"];

uncompletedcities = []
for x in cities:
    dockerscript = "docker exec -it docker_1 perl ./import.pl %s %s" % (x,x)
    p = subprocess.Popen(dockerscript, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    error = p.communicate()
    if p.returncode != 0:
            uncompletedcities.append(x)

    while p.poll() == None:
        print p.stderr.read()

print (uncompletedcities)
```

But I could not get the correct output.

Using

```
check_output(["pidof", "perl"])
```

I return the pid of the script thats in question.

My question is, how do I go about using subprocess, or another library in python to monitor an already running pid, until it reaches EOL, and terminates with a return code.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the PID you want to wait for, you can use `psutils` , https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.wait_procs